# Neo4j Load csv on create set if not null

Tags: neo4j

Is there a way in Neo4j to use ON CREATE SET with an IF NOT NULL?

I have a cvs file as such:

```
employeeid,firstname,lastname,suffix,title
1,john,baker,,mr
2,ellie,johnston,,mrs,
3,bob,smith,jr,,
```

My current load statement:

```
LOAD CSV from 'file://file' AS line
WITH line
MERGE (a:Employee {id:TOINT(line.`employeeid`)}) 
ON CREATE SET a.firstname = line.`firstname`, a.lastname = line.`lastname`, a.suffix = line.`suffix`
```

How would I change this so it won't set an attribute if null but still set those that have values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set an attribute to null it will actually not be created.